# Fetch all results MYSQL table - 6 items per row. If less than 6 results exist, list advert templates?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a total of 8 results/users in my MYSQL table 'users'.

I want to display 6 results/user profiles per row. This is what I'm currently getting as the result:

```
1st Result.   2nd Result.  3rd Result.  4th Result.   5th Result.  6th Result

7th Result.   8th Result.    No More Results.....
```

Not all users will have a profile image, so my code also checks for a profile image and if it can't find one it will use a template profile image instead.

It is a requirement for each row to be complete with a minimum of 6 results/profiles. Where there is not enough results/profiles to complete a row, then I am trying to fill in the remaining non existent profiles with an advert template 'advertise your profile here'.

The advert template image is stored in the following directory:

```
<div><img src="data/profile/0/main/advert.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></div>';
```

This is my desired result:

```
1st Result.   2nd Result.  3rd Result.  4th Result.   5th Result.  6th Result

7th Result.   8th Result.    9 Ad Here.  10 Ad Here.  11 Ad Here.  12 Ad Here.
```

Here is the code that I currently have.

```
   <?php $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser'";
        $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


        $limit = 6; 
        $chunks = array_chunk($result, $limit);

        foreach($chunks as $chunk){
        echo '<div id="category_case_holder">';

        foreach($chunk as $chunkItem){



        $i = htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']);
        $filename = "data/profile/$i/main/profile.jpg"; 
        if (file_exists($filename)) {
        echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/'.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';
        }else{
        echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/0/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';

        } }

        echo '</div>';

        } ?>
```

However, the code is still not giving the desired result. Please can someone help me improve/amend the code to get it to give me the result i require. Thank you.

Comment: What is returned? or should we guess that?

Comment: limit the results in your sql statement ```LIMIT 6```

Comment: @Luuk apologies question updated for clarity, the first row contains 6 results, whilst the second row contains only 2. A total of 8 results. But i want to complete the second row with 4 advert place holder templates - totalling 6 items to complete the row

Comment: @WanPeninsula that's not what my question asks. I don't want only 6 results. I want unlimited sql results, but a maximum of 6 per row. Where any row is lacking a full 6 results, i want to complete the row with an advertise here place holder image. Please re-read question.

Comment: Why do you not simply add the `place holders` when the count is not a multiple of 6?

Comment: @Luuk i've never programmed code before in my life until a week ago. This is all new to me and i'm self taught. How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am copying your complete code because i change some formatting, which makes code more readable.

The inserted pieces of code use the variable `$nrProfilesOnScreen`

You might need to change the line that contains '?????' ....

```
<?php    
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "******", "test");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE status = 'active' AND usertype = 'advertiser'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $limit = 6; 
    $chunks = array_chunk($result, $limit);
    $nrProfilesOnScreen = 0;

    foreach($chunks as $chunk){
        echo '<div id="category_case_holder">';

        foreach($chunk as $chunkItem){

            $i = htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']);
            $filename = "data/profile/$i/main/profile.jpg"; 
            if (file_exists($filename)) {
                echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/'.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';
            }else{
                echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.htmlspecialchars($chunkItem['user_id']).'"><img src="data/profile/0/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>';
            } 
            $nrProfilesOnScreen++;
        }

        for (; $nrProfilesOnScreen % $limit !=0; ) {
            echo '<div id="prime"><a href="profile.php?id='.'?????'.'"><img src="data/profile/0/main/profile.jpg" alt="Profile" height="100%" width="100%"></a></div>' . PHP_EOL;
            $nrProfilesOnScreen++;
        }

       echo '</div>';

    }

?>
```

The `%` operator is explained here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

The `for (;$nrProfilesOnScreen % $limit;) { }`  may seem strange, 
it's an alternative for `while ($nrProfilesOnScreen % $limit !=0) {}`